# Android ListView with two buttons set visibility issue

Tags: android

I have [`Drag Sort Listview`](https://github.com/bauerca/drag-sort-listview) with following items.

1) TextView
  2) Two buttons (ON and OFF, At a time only one button is visible)

[Image with OFF state](http://postimg.org/image/xbo47xghv/).
 [Image with ON state](http://postimg.org/image/g3a55icph/).

My issue is, when user click on ON, and scroll the listview and come back to that item, it will not change to ON.

I tried :

```
public class Item {

    public String title;  
    boolean selected = false;

}
public void setSelected(boolean selected) {
    this.selected = selected;
}
```

Inside getView() method :

```
 public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
            ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        if (v != convertView && v != null) {
            ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
            TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtsettingname);
            ImageButton btnoff = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.btnoff);
            ImageButton btnon = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.btnon);
            holder.title = tv;
            holder.btnoff = btnoff;
            holder.btnon = btnon;
            v.setTag(holder);
        }
        final ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
        String albums = getItem(position).title;
        holder.btnoff.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                try {
                    ImageButton cb = (ImageButton) v;
                    Item _state = (Item) cb.getTag();
                    _state.setSelected(false);
                    holder.btnon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    holder.btnoff.setVisibility(View.GONE);


            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
    holder.btnon.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                ImageButton cb = (ImageButton) v;
                Item _state = (Item) cb.getTag();
                _state.setSelected(true);

                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                holder.btnoff.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.btnon.setVisibility(View.GONE);



            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

    holder.title.setText(albums);
    Item state = myarrraylist.get(position);

    if (state.isSelected()) {
        holder.btnon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.btnoff.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else {
        holder.btnon.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.btnoff.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    holder.btnon.setTag(state);

    return v;
}
```

Please help.

Comment: You need to maintain a list of checked items positions in your `Adapter` and validate the state of buttons in `getView()` method...

Comment: You have to manage the state in `getview` method of your `adapter`. because on scrolling when your `getview` called it dont maintain the state of the button.

Comment: @GopalRao I update my question, please check.

Comment: @user3110424 I update my question, have a look.

Comment: Check the status in your `getview` method. you can work with a global and local variable if the status has been changed then show the changed status in `getview`.

Comment: Use a `globalVariable` to track the state of the button. Use a `localVariable` to get the current status of the button. If the state has been changed apply that change to your button. That should do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply you need to maintain the selected state of ON or OFF, just save the position of your Button and fetch it and just save the state for more details you can see [how recycling of ListView works](http://android.amberfog.com/?p=296). Also for a working demo example you can check my blog which  [Rat-a-tat-a-tat Ratatouille](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22602934/726863) has pointed out in this answer.

I am only showing for `btnoff` Button same way you can do it for other as well

`Psuedo code` in your code would be something like,

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
            ViewGroup parent) {
           ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.title tv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtsettingname);
            holder.btnoff btnoff = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnoff);
            holder.btnon btnon = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnon);

        holder.btnoff.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            int pos = (Integer)v.getTag();
        myarrraylist.get(pos).setSelected(false);
        }
    });

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
        else{
    holder = convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.btnoff btnoff.setTag(position);
        holder.btnoff btnon.setTag(position);


    if (myarrraylist.get(position).isSelected()) {
        holder.btnon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.btnoff.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else {
        holder.btnon.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.btnoff.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You will have to maintain state for the bttons. some samples include in [here](http://lalit3686.blogspot.in/2012/06/today-i-am-going-to-show-how-to-deal.html).

set the tag in the `getView` method to the button, and get the tag in the `onClick` Listener to set the state.

Comment: @LalitPoptani - thts your blog :)

Answer (score 0):

add `myarrraylist.set(position, _state);` in `onClick` listeners, so you will update state of a button from global array.

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
            ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        if (v != convertView && v != null) {
            ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
            TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtsettingname);
            ImageButton btnoff = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.btnoff);
            ImageButton btnon = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.btnon);
            holder.title = tv;
            holder.btnoff = btnoff;
            holder.btnon = btnon;
            v.setTag(holder);
        }
        final ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
        String albums = getItem(position).title;
        holder.btnoff.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                try {
                    ImageButton cb = (ImageButton) v;
                    Item _state = (Item) cb.getTag();
                    _state.setSelected(false);

                    holder.btnon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    holder.btnoff.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                    myarrraylist.set(position, _state);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
    holder.btnon.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                ImageButton cb = (ImageButton) v;
                Item _state = (Item) cb.getTag();
                _state.setSelected(true);

                holder.btnoff.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.btnon.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                myarrraylist.set(position, _state);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

    holder.title.setText(albums);
    Item state = myarrraylist.get(position);

    if (state.isSelected()) {
        holder.btnon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.btnoff.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else {
        holder.btnon.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.btnoff.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    holder.btnon.setTag(state);

    return v;
}
```