# Maintain the state of selected listview Imagebutton on scrolling

Tags: android, listview

I try to implement add to favorites functionality in my app .I have two Image-buttons  a`ddToFavouritiesBtn` and `removeFromFavouritiesBtn`  in list-view . At a time only one Image-button get visible on selection.

My problem is , when I select `addToFavouritiesBtn` it gets selected , but when I scroll-down  list-view and come back to that Image-button , it remains unselected.

Please tell me how to maintain state of the selected items on scrolling.

**Here is my code.**

```
public class Product{

  private boolean selected = false;

  public boolean isSelected() {
    return selected;
}

public void setSelected(boolean selected) {
    this.selected = selected;
  }
}
```

**ProdctListAdaptet.class**

```
public class ProductListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Activity activity;
private List<Product> productItems;
private Context context;
int pos;
int flag = 0 ;

public ProductListAdapter(Context context,Activity activity, List<Product> productItems,int flag) {
    this.activity = activity;
    this.productItems = productItems;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
   // ProductHolder holder = null;

    final   ProductHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {

        holder = new ProductHolder();

        LayoutInflater  inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.product_list_row_item, parent,false);

        holder.thumbNail = (ImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.product_image);
        holder.title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);

        holder.btnAddFavourite  = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.AddFavourites);
        holder.btnRemoveFavourite  = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.RemoveFavourites);


        holder.btnAddFavourite.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                flag = 1;
                System.out.println("Add favourities");
                pos = (Integer) v.getTag();
                productItems.get(pos).setSelected(false);

                holder.btnAddFavourite.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                holder.btnRemoveFavourite.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                //notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });

        holder.btnRemoveFavourite.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                flag = 2;
                System.out.println("Remove favorities");
                pos = (Integer) v.getTag();

                productItems.get(pos).setSelected(true);

                holder.btnAddFavourite.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.btnRemoveFavourite.setVisibility(View.GONE);

               // notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
        });
          convertView.setTag(holder);

    } else {

        holder = (ProductHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.btnAddFavourite.setTag(position);
    holder.btnRemoveFavourite.setTag(position);

    Product state = productItems.get(position);
    System.out.println("Product position -----> " + state);

    if (state.isSelected()) {

        System.out.println("Selected state ******************* " + state.isSelected());
        System.out.println("selected");
        holder.btnAddFavourite.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.btnRemoveFavourite.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else {
        System.out.println("Selected state ******************* " + state.isSelected());
        System.out.println(" not selected");
        holder.btnAddFavourite.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.btnRemoveFavourite.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    }

    convertView.setTag(holder);
    return convertView;
}

    final Product product = (Product) productItems.get(position);
    //final  Product product = (Product) getItem(position);

  holder.thumbNail.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
    holder.title.setText(product.getName());


Picasso.with(activity).load(product.getHref())
            .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_default_banner)
            .into(holder.thumbNail);

private class ProductHolder {
    TextView title;
    ImageView thumbNail;
    ImageButton btnAddFavourite;
    ImageButton btnRemoveFavourite;
}
```

}

Comment: your button is not showing or you use something to selection? backgroung or checkbox?

Comment: I use ImageButtons itself for selection and unselection of listview items.When I click on btnAddFavourite Imagebutton (Empty heart image)  , its visibility bacames gaon and other btnRemoveFavourite(Red heart image) became visible .  But when I scrolldown  visiility of btnRemoveFavourite has gone again.

Comment: can you please set that click listener just before settag position

Comment: I tried it , but same problem has occured.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use youradapetr.notifydatasetchanged() after change in dataset in your button onclick function 
, in your case simply add notifyDataSetChanged(); like below in both function

```
        holder.btnAddFavourite.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                System.out.println("Add favourities");
                int pos = (Integer) v.getTag();
                productItems.get(pos).setSelected(false);

                holder.btnAddFavourite.setVisibility(View.GONE);
             holder.btnRemoveFavourite.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
```

Comment: @Monika if this answer helped you then accept or notify the problem

Comment: If I add notifyDataSetChanged() , btnRemoveFavourite is not visible onClickListner . Please suggest if there is any other  solution to this.

Comment: @Monika please check what state.isSelected() is returning if it returning false to all then your dataset is not properly updating, also post yore complete adapter class

Comment: @Pavam  I updated adapter class , please take a look . And the  reference link is  :- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22602622/android-listview-with-two-buttons-set-visibility-issue

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is inside the onClickListener. Use position which is coming as parameters instead of pos for setting the state inside your listeners.

```
holder.btnAddFavourite.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            System.out.println("Add favourities");
            productItems.get(position).setSelected(false);
            holder.btnAddFavourite.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.btnRemoveFavourite.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });

holder.btnRemoveFavourite.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            System.out.println("Remove favorities");
            productItems.get(position).setSelected(true);

            holder.btnAddFavourite.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.btnRemoveFavourite.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        }
    });
```

EDIT 1:-

Can your try below getView method. I think you are setting incorrect state in onclick listener. You are setting setSelected(true) in btnRemoveFavourite but it should be setSelected(false). Same applies for btnAddFavorite.

Please try below code and accept the answer if its correct.

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    final ProductHolder holder = null;
    if (convertView == null) {

        holder = new ProductHolder();

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.product_list_row_item, parent, false);

        holder.thumbNail = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.product_image);
        holder.title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        holder.btnAddFavourite = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.AddFavourites);
        holder.btnRemoveFavourite = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.RemoveFavourites);

        convertView.setTag(holder);

    } else {

        holder = (ProductHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    final Product product = productItems.get(position);

    holder.btnAddFavourite.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            product.setSelected(true);

            holder.btnAddFavourite.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.btnRemoveFavourite.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }
    });

    holder.btnRemoveFavourite.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            product.setSelected(false);

            holder.btnAddFavourite.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.btnRemoveFavourite.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        }
    });

    if (product.isSelected()) {

        System.out.println("Selected state ******************* " + state.isSelected());
        System.out.println("selected");
        holder.btnAddFavourite.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.btnRemoveFavourite.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        System.out.println("Selected state ******************* " + state.isSelected());
        System.out.println(" not selected");
        holder.btnAddFavourite.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.btnRemoveFavourite.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    }

    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: Position is not issue  , but  visibility of selected  btnRemoveFavourite  has gone on scrolling .

Comment: @Monika can you check my edit. Try using that getView method.

Comment: I have tried it and even other combinations too , but its not working.Statement in else part is printing but btnRemoveFavourite is not visible.

Answer (score 0):

The Issue:

getView() in your adapter gets called from time to time. As a result, if the selected state is not set for the button, it will revert to the original state.

Solution:

Keep a boolean in the model class [Product] with getters and setters:

```
boolean didSelect;

 public boolean isDidSelect() {
        return didSelect;
    }

public void setDidSelect(boolean didSelect) {
        this.didSelect = didSelect;
    }
```

In getView(), depending on the value in the boolean set the selection of the button.

Comment: you are right , adapter gets called thats why selected   state remains false , and btnRemoveFavourite remains invisible.

Comment: please update your question with what you have done.

Comment: I updated my code earlier please have a look  , and this is what I have done till now. State of btnRemoveFavourite remains invisible on scrolling because view gets recycled , and thats why button state is not going to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

Here i am giving a simple demo for you,You Can update it according your requirement,I hope you will get your Solution.

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
String s[] = { "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L",
        "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y",
        "Z" };

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    List<Product> products = new ArrayList<Product>();
    ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
        Product item = new Product();
        item.setCheck(false);
        item.setName(s[i].toString());
        products.add(item);
    }
    ProductListAdapter ac = new ProductListAdapter(MainActivity.this, R.layout.row,
            products);

    list.setAdapter(ac);

}// on create method end

class ProductListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private List<Product> productItems;

    Context context;
    int layoutId;



    public ProductListAdapter(Context context, int layoudId, List<Product> productItems) {
        // super(context,productItems);

        this.layoutId = layoudId;
        this.context = context;
        this.productItems = productItems;


    }

    public class ProductHolder {
        ImageView image;

        TextView name;

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
            ViewGroup parent) {
        final ProductHolder holder;
        Product rowitems = productItems.get(position);
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            convertView = mInflater.inflate(layoutId, parent, false);
            holder = new ProductHolder();

            holder.name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);

            holder.image = (ImageView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.invite_click);
            holder.image.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.green);
            convertView.setTag(holder);

        }

        else {
            holder = (ProductHolder) convertView.getTag();

        }

        holder.image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (productItems.get(position).isCheck) {
                    productItems.get(position).isCheck = false;
                    // holder.image.setImageBitmap(null);
                    holder.image.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.green);

                } else {
                    productItems.get(position).isCheck = true;
                    holder.image
                            .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.green_tick);
                }

            }
        });

        if (productItems.get(position).isCheck) {

            productItems.get(position).isCheck = true;
            holder.image.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.green_tick);

        } else {
            productItems.get(position).isCheck = false;
            holder.image.setImageBitmap(null);
            holder.image.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.green);
        }
        holder.name.setText(rowitems.getName());

        Log.e("name----->", productItems.get(position).toString());

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return productItems.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return productItems.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return productItems.indexOf(getItem(position));
    }

}
```

}

Comment: public class Product {

 String name;
 public boolean isCheck = false;

 public boolean isCheck() {
  return isCheck;
 }

 public void setCheck(boolean isCheck) {
  this.isCheck = isCheck;
 }

 public void toggleChecked() {
  isCheck = !isCheck;
 }

 public String getName() {
  return name;
 }

 public void setName(String name) {
  this.name = name;
 }

}